# problems connecting

Tags: help

Whenever I try to open it or configure, I get this:

```
11/6/2015 7:05:39 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
11/6/2015 7:05:47 AM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
11/6/2015 7:05:47 AM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
11/6/2015 7:05:47 AM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
11/6/2015 7:05:47 AM.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
11/6/2015 7:05:50 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
11/6/2015 7:05:50 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
11/6/2015 7:05:51 AM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
11/6/2015 7:05:51 AM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
11/6/2015 7:05:51 AM.200 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'wisctorbridge03' (fresh): $A17A40775FBD2CA1184BF80BFC330A77ECF9D0E9~wisctorbridge03 at 128.105.214.163 
11/6/2015 7:05:51 AM.200 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
11/6/2015 7:05:51 AM.600 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'fdctorbridge01' (fresh): $FDC5BA65D93B6BCA5EBDF8EF8E4FA936B7F1F8E5~fdctorbridge01 at 192.240.101.106 
11/6/2015 7:05:51 AM.600 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
11/6/2015 7:05:51 AM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
11/6/2015 7:05:52 AM.200 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'fdctorbridge02' (fresh): $2BD466989944867075E872310EBAD65BC88C8AEF~fdctorbridge02 at 50.7.176.114 
11/6/2015 7:05:52 AM.200 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
11/6/2015 7:05:53 AM.400 [WARN] Our clock is 1 days, 21 hours, 54 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2015-11-08 10:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
11/6/2015 7:05:53 AM.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
11/6/2015 7:05:53 AM.900 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
11/6/2015 7:05:55 AM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
11/6/2015 7:05:55 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
11/6/2015 7:05:55 AM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
11/6/2015 7:05:55 AM.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host FC562097E1951DCC41B7D7F324D88157119BB56D at 128.105.214.162:8080) 
11/6/2015 7:05:55 AM.800 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
11/6/2015 7:05:55 AM.800 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
11/6/2015 7:05:56 AM.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 2; recommendation warn; host 1E326AAFB3FCB515015250D8FCCC8E37F91A153B at 128.105.214.161:8080) 
11/6/2015 7:05:56 AM.800 [WARN] 2 connections have failed: 
11/6/2015 7:05:56 AM.800 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
11/6/2015 7:05:56 AM.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 3; recommendation warn; host 0E858AC201BF0F3FA3C462F64844CBFFC7297A42 at 131.252.210.150:8080) 
11/6/2015 7:05:56 AM.900 [WARN] 3 connections have failed: 
11/6/2015 7:05:56 AM.900 [WARN]  3 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
11/6/2015 7:05:56 AM.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```